# Get position of a point with known distance between other points

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

If there are $(n+1)$ points in $m$ dimensional space,
and we have known the Euclidean distances from one point "$B$" to the other $n$ points "$A_1,\ldots,A_n$", and known the positions of these $n$ points "$A_1,\ldots,A_n$", 
how can we get the position of the point "$B$" in $m$ dimensional space?

I understand it will form Two times simultaneous equations, as below example, but what is a good mathematical method for solving it?  (Assume the points are in higher dimensional space, where m > 3)

*Example: 
Assume the poisition of B is ($X_1,\ldots,X_m$), and the distance equations with other n point are below. I want to solve ($X_1,\ldots,X_m$)
($X_1-2)^2+\ldots+(X_m-4)^2$=5 
($X_1-6)^2+\ldots+(X_m-7)^2$=9 
($X_1-9)^2+\ldots+(X_m-5)^2$=11 
... (totally n equations)

Comment: Well, there's a fairly obvious system of equations to write down.  Do you have a specific example?

Comment: Related (a low-dimensional discussion): [how to find the right position for representing distance between points when 4 points](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17498/how-to-find-the-right-position-for-representing-distance-between-points-when-4-p)

Comment: A keyword for searching is [trilateration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilateration).  A reasonable approach, studied in the literature, is [multi-dimensional scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_scaling) .

Comment: To Mark McClure: I have modified my question.

Comment: Sorry, my original question is not clear. I have modified my question description: It is in higher dimensional space. I have known the positions of these n points, and their distances to B. I want to get B. (Maybe it needs to solve the Two times simultaneous equations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll show you how it can be done for $m = 2$.

$$\begin{align}
(x_1 - a_1)^2 + (x_2 - a_2)^2 & = d_a^2\\
(x_1 - b_1)^2 + (x_2 - b_2)^2 & = d_b^2\\
(x_1 - c_1)^2 + (x_2 - c_2)^2 & = d_c^2\\
\end{align}$$

When you multiply each equation out you get this:

$$x_1^2 - 2a_1x_1 + a_1^2 + x_2^2 - 2 a_2x_2 + a_2^2= d_a^2$$

Which can be simplified to something that looks like this:
$$x_1^2 + k_1 x_1 + x_2^2 + k_2 x_2 = k_3$$

Put all the equations in this form, then subtract the first equation from the rest.  These transformations have not effected the overall solution space of the equations.

$$\begin{align}
x_1^2 + a_{11} x_1 + x_2^2 + a_{12} x_2 & = e_1 \\
a_{21} x_1 + a_{22} x_2 & = e_2\\
a_{31} x_1 + a_{32}  x_2 & = e_3\\
\end{align}$$

If $a_{21}, a_{22}, a_{31}, a_{32}$ form a nonsingular matrix then you can solve the linear system and have a single point to test against the first equation.

The intuition here is that the intersection of two n+1-dimensional spheres will always be a subset of an n-dimensional plane.  Two circles will always intersect along a line, and two spheres will always intersect along a plane.

Comment: Dear NovaDenizen, thanks for your method! But it seems that this method will require at least 5 equations while m=3?

Comment: You can simplify the problem of finding the intersection of n m-dimensional hyperspheres into the intersection of a single m-dimensional hypersphere and a linear space.  The linear space might be empty or a single point or be a space with up to m-n+1 basis vectors.  There's not really a way to simplify it more than that without more knowlege of the problem.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Your solution really really helps me. Thank you too much.