# Finding points satisfying given constraints on their neighborhoods.

Tags: combinatorics, metric-spaces

Let $x_1,\cdots x_n$ and $y_1,\cdots y_m$ be *arbitrary* points in $\mathbb{R}^k$. For a given metric $d$ and a given $\epsilon>0$ define: $$A_i\equiv \{\, j \quad |\quad  d(x_i,y_j)<\epsilon\},$$ i.e. the set of labels of the points $y_j$ falling in the neighborhood of $x_i$, for $i=1,\cdots n$.
Clearly the $A_i$ can be determined for any sets of arbitrary points $x_i$ and $y_j$.

My question is about reversing the previous path: given an *arbitrary* family of subsets of $\{1,\cdots,m\}$, is it always possible to find a suitable metric $d$, a suitable $\epsilon$ and suitable points such that the $A_i$ satisfy the previous definition?

For example, let $A_1\equiv\{1,2\}$ and $A_2\equiv\{3,4\}$. A solution in $\mathbb{R}$ is given by points $(y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4)\equiv(1,2,3,4)$ and $(x_1,x_2)=(1.5,3.5)$, the usual euclidean metric and any $\epsilon \in (0.5,1.5)$. However, if you add $A_3\equiv\{1,4\}$ and $A_4\equiv\{2,3\}$ there is no solution in $\mathbb{R}$ (but I could still find a solution in $\mathbb{R^2}$ by drawing). So maybe it is enough to raise dimensionality to find a solution?

Comment: Let $A_i$ be a subset of $\{1,\cdots,m\}$, for $i=1,\cdots,n$. Is it always possible to place vectors $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ and $y_1,\cdots,y_m$ such that, for each $x_i$ in the first group, $A_i$ is the set of labels of the second group which are contained in his $\epsilon$-neighborhood?

Comment: I reformulated the question by reversing the presentation and introducing formal notation for the set $A_i$. I also added a solution for a particular case. Thanks again for helping clarifying the presentation.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed it seems related: an analogous question would be whether any given set of non-negative numbers can arise as the set of pairwise distances of some points in some metric space. Intuitively a negative answer would depend on the triangular inequality preventing some configurations. Nicely, in the example it was enough to go "one-up" to get a solution...

Comment: Related: [Define positions of a set of points given (only) the distances between them](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/671183/define-positions-of-a-set-of-points-given-only-the-distances-between-them).  Also [When can we achieve given distances between four points?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17498/when-can-we-achieve-given-distances-between-four-points).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me make some quick observations about the Euclidean plane and the feasible sets of indices (subsets of $\{1,\ldots,m\}$).  The problem is essentially that of [Venn diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram), in which the centers of circles play the role of the $y_j, j=1,..,m$ and points $x_i$ are placed in regions of overlap/nonoverlap of circles according to the desired subset $A_i$.

It is well known (since Venn, 1880) that in the Euclidean plane the maximum number of circles of equal size ($\epsilon$-neighborhoods) that can be arranged to give all possible subsets is three.  Additional circles might be added to such a diagram, but not all possibilities of overlap/nonoverlap will be achieved.

The generalization to $d$-dimensional Euclidean spaces has been considered in the literature.  A result that at most $d+1$ "independent" (hyper)spheres are possible in $d$-dimensional space was reported by [Rényi, Rényi, and Surányi (1951)](http://www.combinatorics.org/files/Surveys/ds5/VennOtherEJC.html), with some corrections to that paper given by Branko Grünbaum (1975).  This latter paper won the MAA Writing Award in 1976 and may be read online, [Venn Diagrams and Independent Families of Sets](http://www.maa.org/programs/maa-awards/writing-awards/venn-diagrams-and-independent-families-of-sets).

It follows that $d = m-1$ is a sufficiently high dimension to allow solutions $x_i, y_j$ for all $n = 2^m$ possible subsets $A_i$ of $\{1,\ldots,m\}$.

Comment: I can only say "wow!". I felt that the solution was over the corner when I looked at your translation in terms of Venn diagrams. But then my reasoning was:  if the number $k$ of *distinct* $A_i$ (this can happen in my setting) is less or equal than the maximum number of independent regions generated by the $m$ points then the $A_i$ are feasible sets of indices. So $d$ solves $k\le 2^{d+1}$, from which $d\ge \frac{log(k/2)}{log(2)}$. I think it's a way of stating the conclusion from a different starting point. Thanks so much for giving thought to it! And for giving that classic references.